# How to change the color shown in app window when you switch app

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to change the panel color (i dont know what is it called, check the photo) without changing the primaryColor in ThemeData.

[image]

I am using flutter for this project. Can this be done in flutter itself or should i need to do it in android code.

Answer (score 0):

That panel is generally called the **AppBar**.

You can change its color by assigning an appBar `backgroundColor` when you return the Scaffold of your Screen class.

Here is a quick sample :

```
appBar: AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.green
)
```

[Here is a link to the Scaffold class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

Please go through the properties provided by the [AppBar class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) as well.

Comment: you saying setting this in Scaffold will work? what do you mean in the main.dart? it is not working that way.

Comment: I have updated my answer for you. Can you provide a code sample of your class file.

Comment: the color of panel is not changing by settig appbar bg color. changing the primaryColor is ThemeData does but that affects everything inside the app, i wont to avoid that.

Comment: Can you please provide your code sample of your appbar code as well in the question above ?